# How to make Accurev elements inactive after promotion from time-based stream

Tags: command-line-interface, accurev

Accurev "User CLI Guide" says "*Promoting from a time-based stream to its parent does not remove the elements from the default group
of the time-based stream.*"

So the question is how to make elements inactive after promotion from time-based stream?

UPD: Since I promoted my changes with `accurev promote -d -s <stream>` command, then the command to purge them is

```
accurev purge -s <stream> `accurev stat -d -s <stream> -f l`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the files that your promoted from your time based stream and perform a "Revert to Basis", ie purge operation.